# Is it OK to install Jessie Lite on a Raspberry 1 model B?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, cluster, nfs

My problems started when I used it as a master node in a cluster with 3 more Pi2B as slaves. Nfs4 did not run because of the portmap issue and then I could not install openjdk7 because of the packages missing in the mirror of Raspbian.

Comment: Have you tried it? I don't see why this would not work.

Comment: @SteveRobillard If I remember correctly, Jessie used to be incompatible with the Pi 1 because of hardware constraints. That might be the reason he asked.

Answer (score 1):

It should be okay to install Jessie on the Pi 1. It's compatible now.

Besides, you won't break the Pi if you installed something incompatible. So relax and flash away.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm it works on a Raspberry Pi Model B Rev. 2, as well as the Raspberry Pi Zero. I have both of these Pis, and have installed and successfully run Jessie Lite. It works very well, in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had any issues still running a full blown Java web application. Been two weeks today.